# How to convert the calculating result to int in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
count = "400"/3 - 1;
```

How to convert the above `count` to `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var countInt:int = int(count);

Answer (score 0):

Integers are easy if you use [math](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html)!

Specifically, Math.floor(count) will give you the classic integer version of this by throwing away the non-integer part, while Math.round(count) will round to the nearest integer. I'd suggest going with Math.floor though as it's probably closer to what you mean.

Comment: But `Math.round` returns a `Number`,how to convert it to `int` ?

Comment: var countInt:int = int(count);